# I want users to be able to login once and not worry about having to login again until they explicitly logout using FormsAUthentication in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I want users to be able to login once and not worry about having to login again until they explicitly logout using FormsAUthentication in ASP.Net 3.5.

I have mention in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="_AuthCookie" loginUrl="~/LogIn.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="50000000"></forms>
</authentication>
```

But the user logging out after 20 mins.

Please help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

Check IIS.

IIS supersedes what your web.config sets as a timeout.

Select Default Web Site > Properties > Home Directory > Application Settings > Configuration > Options.

I'm not sure what the max is, or if you can set it to only expire once the user actually logs out (`FormsAuthentication.Signout() + Session.Abandon()` )

Perhaps using slidingExpiration would help, but not sure.